# SwiftUI - List scrolling underneath status bar text

Tags: ios, swiftui

I Create List and add VStack inside and added some views inside VStack. When I run the project, I observer scrolling of List going beyond the safe area. FYI if I remove Frame property still same result.[Simulator gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1PgL.gif)

```
struct ContentView : View {
var body: some View {

    List(0..<5) { item in
        HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.top, spacing: 5) {
            Image(systemName: "photo")
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 10) {
                Text("USA")
                    .font(.headline)

                Text("This is an extremely long string that will never fit even the widest of Phones Excerpt From: Paul Hudson. “SwiftUI by Example”. Apple Books. ")
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.red)
        .onAppear() {
            print("on Appear")

    }.onDisappear() {
        print("on Disappear")
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inspired by Shauket Sheikh. You can directly add the .padding(.top) to the List and it's done. No need for a VStack.

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
            List(0..<5) { item in
                HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.top, spacing: 5) {
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                    VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 10) {
                        Text("USA")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("This is an extremely long string that will never fit even the widest of Phones Excerpt From: Paul Hudson. “SwiftUI by Example”. Apple Books. ")
                            .lineLimit(nil)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
                .onAppear() {
                    print("on Appear")
            }.onDisappear() {
                print("on Disappear")
            }
        .padding(.top)
    }
}
```

Comment: it means for each view we need to do this thing? for left , top and right and bottom?

Comment: Updated the code, you only need to add .padding(.all) to the List. No need for VStack.

Comment: yes, this works. need to make padding .all not only top

Comment: I think this breaks translucency on views list extends under: like TabBar and NavigationView. Also if you have big title in NavigationView and you add padding at the top, it will break fluid animation in title collapsing

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem with my `ScrollView`

My solution was simpler than the rest, so give this a shot:

Just add `.clipped()` modifier to your `List` or `ScrollView` and this should prevent your content from scrolling out of its bounds.

And you can then combine this with `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)` if you want your content to still scroll off screen from the bottom. But watch out - `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)` has to come after `.clipped()` if you want this effect.

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `VStack` and set `.padding()` of it.

Code :

```
 struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View { 
       VStack {
            List(0..<5) { item in
                HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.top, spacing: 5) {
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                    VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 10) {
                        Text("USA")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("This is an extremely long string that will never fit even the widest of Phones Excerpt From: Paul Hudson. “SwiftUI by Example”. Apple Books. ")
                            .lineLimit(nil)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
                .onAppear() {
                    print("on Appear")
            }.onDisappear() {
                print("on Disappear")
            }
        }.padding()
     }
  }
```

Comment: better to make padding .all not only .top  because in landscape or your view still go beyond the safe area also no need seprate VStack

Comment: @ShauketSheikh yes, just use `.padding()` for that.