# SwiftUI NavigationView collapse on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How do I get the NavigationBar to collapse from `large` to `inline` when I scroll? Right now the `ScrollView` is scrolling it's content beneath the `NavigationBar`'s title, but in front of the back button.

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0...5) { _ in
                        ExerciseView()
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Testing", displayMode: .automatic)
```

Answer (score 14):

The first thing to note is that `navigationBarTitle` should be a modifier on `ScrollView`, not `NavigationView`.

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0...5) { _ in
                    ExerciseView()
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Testing", displayMode: .automatic)
    }
}
```

From the documentation for `navigationBarTitle`:

> This modifier only takes effect when this view is inside of and visible within a NavigationView.

Another thing to keep in mind, according to the documentation for `displayMode`:

> ```swift
> case automatic
> ```
>
> > Inherit the display mode from the previous navigation item.

If you use `.automatic`, you're telling the `NavigationView` to use the same display mode as the previous navigation item, meaning that if you navigated from a view with a `displayMode` of `.inline`, then your new view will also inherit that display mode.

After moving the `navigationBarTitle` modifier to the `ScrollView`, however, your issue still remains - the scroll view scrolls underneath both the navigation bar title and the back button text as if the navigation bar's background is missing.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049763/swiftui-list-scrolling-underneath-status-bar-text/57050307#57050307) address a similar issue with a `List` scrolling underneath the status bar text, so I used their suggestion of adding padding to the `ScrollView`. That sort of works in that the scroll view now scrolls underneath the navigation bar properly, but the navigation bar still doesn't collapse from `.large` to `.inline` when you scroll.

This really just feels like a bug to me. There shouldn't be any need to set padding on the scroll view to begin with. The view doesn't know if it's going to be nested inside a `NavigationView`, so why should it have to specify padding just to make the navigation bar work properly?

In the meantime, I would just suggest setting the `displayMode` to `.inline`. At least that way everything will behave as you might expect.

Comment: I have a view with search bar that appears on scroll view pull. The navigation title shows inside the scroll (offset of where I trigger it). I (somewhat) resolved it, base on this answer, by switching from `.automatic` to `.inline` when search was showing.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the ScrollView .padding() to .padding(.leading, 20) and .padding(.trailing, 20) solved a similar issue for me

Answer (score 0):

.padding(.top) for ScrollView helped for me